# How to make this bottom navigation bar?

Tags: android, android-studio

**Hello!**

I just want to know if it's possible to make a bottom navigation bar like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuoKW.png), with this amazing blue center button. I just want the design (xml code). Can you help me?

**Thanks!**

Comment: did you find a solution? please review my response

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can get the effect you want starting from this [tutorial](https://medium.com/material-design-in-action/implementing-bottomappbar-material-components-for-android-f490c4a01708)
then you have to work I guess the  circle so that you can enlarge following another tutorial changing the size try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185103/how-to-define-a-circle-shape-in-an-android-xml-drawable-file) just to warm up and be confident for the concept, then you are going to find five  solutions with the code  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51094118/bottom-navigation-with-fab)

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <!-- Other components and views -->

  <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
      android:id="@+id/bar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
      app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu_24"/>

  <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
      android:id="@+id/fab"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:layout_anchor="@id/bar"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```