# Custome bottom navigation bar in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I just want to create a bottom navigation bar like this. I'm not able to create that overflow button in the middle. How can I design the xml layout...pls help me... 
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51672800/2383176

Comment: @javadroid This is not I 'm searching..But I just managed to create the cutomized xml layout using a Framelayout. Anyway thanks...